# How do I wait for mysqli_multi_query to resolve?

Tags: php, mysqli

Suppose I have code like this:

```
mysqli_multi_query('<first query>');
include_once 'secondQuery.php';
```

This is an enormous simplification, and hopefully I haven't simplified the error out, but `secondQuery.php` relies on `<first query>` to be completed in order to execute properly. When I run the two manually, in the correct order, everything works perfectly. But when I run this, the error I get is consistent with them either executed in the wrong order, or simultaneously.

How would I write the middle line of:

```
mysqli_multi_query('<first query>');
wait for mysqli_multi_query to conclude;
include_once 'secondQuery.php';
```

in correct PHP syntax?

Comment: Not 100% sure but maybe you could put the `mysqli_multi_query` inside an if statement and then do the `include_once`. That way PHP has to wait for mysqli to return a value.

Comment: @J0R1AN No, that will not do anything. You need to ask PHP to wait for MySQL to give a response.

Answer (score -1):

Every time you use [`mysqli_multi_query()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.multi-query.php) you need to execute a blocking loop after it, because this function sends SQL queries to be executed by MySQL asynchronously. An example of a blocking loop which waits for MySQL to process all queries asynchronously is this:

```
$mysqli->multi_query(/* ... */);
do {
    $result = $mysqli->use_result();
    if ($result) {
        // process the results here
        $result->free();
    }
} while ($mysqli->next_result()); // Next result will block and wait for next query to finish
$mysqli->store_result(); // Needed to fetch the error as exception
```

It is always a terrible idea to use [`mysqli_multi_query()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.multi-query.php) in your PHP code. 99.99% of the time there are better ways to achieve what you want. This function has so many downsides that using it should be avoided at all cost.

What you need are database transactions. If your queries depend on each other then you need to switch off implicit commit and commit when all of them execute successfully. You can't achieve this with `mysqli_multi_query()`.

Comment: I see I need to add more context here. `secondQuery.php` is a function I've written to read the database and send data to eBay and Etsy regarding our inventory. It calls after every sale (maybe 5 times per day). <first query> is a function that uploads all the discrepancies discovered by the last stocktake. I call it twice a month at most, and it's write only (no results returned). All I need, is to upload the new quantities, THEN synchronise with other platforms. So writing both functions on the same file isn't an option here.